# Deleted assignment operator error which isn't used

Tags: c++

Implicitly deleted member assignment causes a compile error in code that never calls the assignment operator.

```
#include <vector>

struct A {
    A(int arg) : i{ arg } {}
//    A& operator=(const A& arg) { return *this; }
    const int i;
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v;
    v.emplace_back(1);  // vector of one A initialized to i:1

    // The next line causes this compiler error 'A &A::operator =(const A &)': function was implicitly deleted because 'A' has a data member 'A::i' of const - qualified non - class type
    v.erase(v.begin()); // ending the lifetime of A and but now using the same storage
    v.emplace_back(2);  // vector of one A initialized to i:2
}
```

If I define an assignment operator then the code compiles and, of course, never calls it. Running the code with all special member functions defined shows, as expected, that only the CTOR, and DTOR is called.

So why is this error occurring in multiple compilers?

https://godbolt.org/z/44foEMh6o

Comment: [`erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) requires type to be MoveAssignable (because it will move elements from the right part of the vector). It doesn't matter that it will not be used in this particulat example - compiler doesn't know that and it's not particularly worth it to add an exception to standard for case where compiler can see all usages of a vector.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen But the requirement for assignability does not apply generally and usually occurs when `reserve()` isn't called prior to adding elements. And it's the appending that can trigger assignment, not `erase()` which should never trigger assignment if the last element. Seems like the requirement is misplaced. And appending works fine so long as assignment isn't invoked such as this case or using `reserve()`

Comment: It is required by standard for both [`insert()`](https://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#lib:insert,containers) and [`erase()`](https://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#lib:erase,containers) that `T` is MoveAssignable (or CopyAssignable). AFAIK, compiler is not required to verify that (and it doesn't for `insert()`), but since it is required by standard, it can demand that.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen  Thanks! I switched to using `resize()` and it works though I have to define a default constructor but not an issue. Been trying to find a way to create a modifiable const I can reference but change w/o UB. Looked into placement new, the obvious choice with no luck. But it turns out using a vector does allow it and it passes the constexpr test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider how the `erase` function might be implemented. It might look something like this:

```
constexpr iterator erase(iterator pos) {
    for (auto i = pos; i + 1 != end(); i++) {
        *i = move(*(i + 1));
    }
    pop_back();
    return pos;
}
```

(The real parameter type is `const_iterator`, but let's ignore this detail.)

If you choose to erase the last element of the vector, then the loop will run zero times and the assignment operator will be invoked zero times. However, you still force the compiler to instantiate the entire body of the `erase` function. When this happens, the compiler must perform overload resolution and check whether there is a usable assignment operator. If there is not, a compilation error occurs.

Expecting your program to compile is like expecting this program to compile:

```
void foo() = delete;
void bar(int num_times) {
    while (num_times--) foo();
}
int main() {
    bar(0);
}
```

Would this program compile? Of course not. Even though `foo` will never be invoked, the mere fact that you attempt to compile some code that contains a call to `foo` will make the program ill-formed.

With a `std::vector`, it is possible for you to say "I promise that I will only be removing the last element, so please do not attempt to compile any code that requires the assignment operator". To do this, use the `pop_back` function instead of `erase`.

Comment: Makes sense. I've been trying to find a way to change a const value w/o UB. Putting a struct if a vector seemed like a possibility. Turned out changing `erase()` to `resize()` fixed it and I can now alter the const value in the vector w/o UB which the other approach failed at. This wasn't shown in my question to keep it to the assignment question which defining still invoked UB unlike resizing.

Comment: @doug If you need to change it, then why make it `const`? If you need more help with your problem, please post a separate question with more details.

Comment: I need to change it but not have it changeable by the user and I'd like to avoid the usual get() style and just have others access a value. This gets into the issue of optimization of consts and is a hard problem.

Comment: Here's an example that works and doesn't show UB. https://godbolt.org/z/eKcqjr8of